# MySQL JOIN Query Index optimization

Tags: mysql, join, indexing

I have this query. Assuming no index is created yet, how can i optimize this using index so the query runs faster? How do i create the index?

```
select c.company_name, c.company_id FROM companies AS c 
JOIN users AS u USING(companyid) 
JOIN jobs AS j USING(userid) 
JOIN useraccounts AS ua USING(userid) 
WHERE j.jobid = 10;
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have indexes on all the columns used in the `JOIN` clauses. You can create the indexes either with [`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) or [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) commands:

```
CREATE INDEX u_companyid ON users (companyid);

ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX (companyid);
```

Note that primary keys of tables are already indexed, you don't need to add an index explicitly.

Comment: do you mean i must add index on users.company_id, jobs.user_id and useraccounts.user_id? if yes, am i missing other columns thats needed to be indexed??

Comment: @MarkBonnieVestil exactly

Comment: @Barmar thanks man. How about indexing companies.company_id. Will it help for faster performance on my query above?

Comment: Isn't that the primary key?

Comment: ah yeah, its a primary key. so i guess no need to index. am i right? Thanks a lot buddy

Comment: Yes, I said that in the last line of my answer. Primary keys already have an index.